# Find index location of first occurrence of a specific partial string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with AFRINIC whois data.  I am trying find the location of the first occurrence of a substring.  In is example(pandas dataframe with one column "data" to the left is the index) I am trying to find the substring, "inetnum".  So the result i am looking for is "2750383".

```
    data
20  mnt-lower: info
21  changed: info
22  changed: info
23  changed: info
24  changed: info
25  source: info
26  as-block: info
27  type: info
28  descr: info
29  remarks: info
... ...
2750381 changed: info
2750382 source: info
2750383 inetnum: info
2750384 netname: info
2750385 descr: info
2750386 country: info
2750387 admin-c: info
2750388 tech-c: info
2750389 status: info
```

I have tried:

```
afrinic.data.ne('inetnum').idxmax()
```

But that gives me "[]" because it is looking for the first whole string and produces 0 results.

I have also tried:

```
indices = [i for i, s in enumerate(afrinic.data) if 'inetnum' in s]
```

But this gives me every index number of the word "inetnum" when all I am looking for is the first instance index number.  I could take that list and just use the top number but there has to be a better way to do this.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for check in any position:

```
out = afrinic.data.str.contains('inetnum').idxmax()
print (out)
2750383
```

Or [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) for test start of each string:

```
out = afrinic.data.str.startswith('inetnum').idxmax()
```

EDIT:

More general solution for working if no value matched:

```
m = afrinic.data.str.contains('inetnum')
out = m.idxmax() if m.any() else 'no match'
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! @jezrael

Comment: Just note that if no string is found, the result of `idxmax` will be 0. If this is relevant, you may need to add an extra check.

Comment: If `NaN` is in the column, I get the error: `TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype`

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. Use `next` with a generator expression:

```
first_index = next((i for i, s in enumerate(afrinic.data) if 'inetnum' in s), None)
```

If no valid index is found, then `next` will return `None` as per the fallback argument.

Using `next` with manual iteration will be more efficient than Pandas / NumPy-based methods for larger dataframes where you expect a match near the beginning of your series. Otherwise, you can use `pd.Series.str` methods as per @jezrael's solution.